# Why "result" value is always equal to zero?

Tags: c++

I'm going through a MOOC about an introduction to c++, and am stuck in an exercise about functions. The exercise is about a program that changes a number to the way it was read.
For example:
"1" is read like "one one" so the next number should be
"11" which is read like "two ones" the next number is
"21" -> "one two and one one"
"1211" -> "one one and one two and two ones"
"111221" -> "three ones and two twos and one one " 
"312211"..... and so on
The user should give the starting number and the number of times we should do this operation, and the program should output the last number. Like in the example the input should be "1 5" and the program should print "312211". In the program they just asked to write three functions to complete the code they gave us.

```
void ajouter_chiffre_droit(int& nombre, int chiffre);
void dire_chiffre(int& nombre, int repetitions_chiffre, int chiffre);
int lire_et_dire(int nombre);
```

The part of the program they gave us is this and we should fill the three functions above:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int separer_chiffre_gauche(int& nombre)
{
  int dix(1);
  int temp(nombre);
  while (temp >= 10) {
    dix  *= 10;
    temp /= 10;
  }
  nombre %= dix;
  return temp;
}

/*****************************************************
 * Compléter le code à partir d'ici
 *****************************************************/

void ajouter_chiffre_droit(int& nombre, int chiffre)
{
}

void dire_chiffre(int& nombre, int repetitions_chiffre, int chiffre)
{
}

int lire_et_dire(int nombre)
{
}

/*******************************************
 * Ne rien modifier après cette ligne.
 *******************************************/

void repeter_lire_et_dire(int& nombre, int fois)
{
  while (fois-- > 0) {
    nombre = lire_et_dire(nombre);
  }
}

int main()
{
  int nombre(1);
  int fois(1);
  cin >> nombre >> fois;
  repeter_lire_et_dire(nombre, fois);
  cout << nombre << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

My solution:

```
void ajouter_chiffre_droit(int& nombre, int chiffre)
{
    nombre *= 10 + chiffre;
}

void dire_chiffre(int& nombre, int repetitions_chiffre, int chiffre)
{
    ajouter_chiffre_droit(nombre, repetitions_chiffre);
    ajouter_chiffre_droit(nombre, chiffre);
}

int lire_et_dire(int nombre)
{
    int nombre_temp(nombre), chiffre(0), chiffre_prec(0), rep(1), resultat(0);


    chiffre_prec = separer_chiffre_gauche(nombre_temp);
    do
    {
        chiffre = separer_chiffre_gauche(nombre_temp);
        if(chiffre == chiffre_prec)
        {
            ++rep;
        }
        else
        {

            dire_chiffre(resultat, rep, chiffre_prec);
            rep = 1;
            chiffre_prec=chiffre;
            
        }
    }while(nombre_temp!=0);
    return resultat;

}
```

The function `lire_et_dire` always returns the value 0 and i don't know why if you could please help me that will be great, thanks!
If you didn't understand the problem from me "probably", please read the official problem text [here](https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/_65764bff2f2456fc531af32e52ca0f01_asgnmt-04-cpp-en-16.pdf?Expires=1596758400&Signature=guBYIHRp2OtDDE7es3hBTWUI9WC7QBY5XflOD-uS12vRg7gvHNpcoj8%7EAeD4U7IYvvqSgx1LWKMGs3z%7EbQ1kKYQB5yJYV8Epfw3JSezxZrACbtNwD9YJTseENbYmKiELqBXxPVlqw6SEKKHFxyungpUgPw1JWQOjwQswfI%7EJ52A_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A) it's exercise number 1.

Comment: `nombre` in `ajouter_chiffre_droit` is assigned to `0 * (10 + chiffre)`, `0` multiplied by anything is always `0`.

Comment: The easiest way to get help with such problems is to help yourself, by learning how to use a debugger to step through the code and see the values of variables at each step. Then you would see the obvious problem here as pointed out above.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen `nombre = (nombre * 10) + chiffre;`i changed it with this and still the same problem

Comment: @aymanedu Well, is `chiffre_prec` or `chiffre` a non-zero value? Seems to me that they are also equal to zero all the time. Debugger would have helped you - you can examine value of each and every variable at any point of execution of your code.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen chiffre_prec's value is 1 for me though. in the `1 5` example.

Comment: The problem is the loop condition. When `nombre` is `11` you count the 1s until `nombre_temp` is `0`. But then you quit the loop and never enter the else-branch. Instead do `while(chiffre>0)`.